# Calculate Time DIfference Pandas by columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have column `df['Status']`, which have some objects:

`In: df.Status.unique()
 Out: array([nan, 'Open', 'Plmt', 'SHRT', 'Check'], dtype=object)`

Column:

`In: df['Status']
 Out:   time           Status
2016-01-15 08:55:00    Open
2016-01-15 09:00:00    Plmt
2016-01-15 09:05:00    Plmt
2016-01-15 09:10:00    Plmt
2016-01-15 09:15:00    Plmt
2016-01-15 09:20:00    Plmt
2016-01-15 09:25:00    Plmt
2016-01-15 09:30:00    Plmt
2016-01-15 09:35:00    Plmt
2016-01-15 09:40:00    SHRT`

where `time` is:

`df.index = df['time']
 df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

I want to skip values i dont need('Plmt', 'Check', 'nan'), make new column df['Diff'], where would be the difference in minutes betweeen `'Open' 'SHRT'`.

Im trying like this:

`df['Status'][df['Status'] == 'SHRT'] - df['Status'][df['Status'] == 'Open']`

but in output recieving NaN values:

`time
2016-01-15 08:55:00    NaN
2016-01-15 09:40:00    NaN
2016-01-18 08:30:00    NaN
2016-01-19 14:30:00    NaN
2016-01-19 14:35:00    NaN
2016-01-20 11:10:00    NaN
2016-01-20 11:45:00    NaN`

The expected Ouput must looks like:

`time                   Status        Diff
2016-01-15 08:55:00    Open          NaN
2016-01-15 09:40:00    SHRT          00:45:00
2016-02-15 10:00:00    Open          NaN
2016-02-15 14:15:00    SHRT          02:15:00`

How to get difference in time, can anyone help please?

Comment: What is expected output? There is only one `Open` and one `SHRT` value?

Comment: @jezrael expected ouput is difference in time, from `Open` to `SHRT`: in column there is over 500 values of them

Comment: OK, so please check second link above and create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), add multiple values `Open` and `SHRT` to data sample with expecred output in numbers.

Comment: @jezrael i`ve asked not clearly?

Comment: Sorry, there is only way value `Open` in data?

Comment: and only one value `SHRT` ?

Comment: @jezrael There are several values (Open, SHRT, Plmt, Check), only values Open and SHRT is over 500+, but i need to find difference only between Open & SHRT

Comment: How working `print (df.index[df['Status'] == 'Open'] - df.index[df['Status'] == 'SHRT'])` ?

Comment: @jezrael recieving this `ValueError: cannot add indices of unequal length`

Comment: It means there are different number of `Open` and `SHRT`. So hard to know solution, still [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) missing.

Comment: @jezrael Ok, i`ll try to make description better

Comment: Super, mainly what happen if different numbe of values of `Open` and `SHRT`, what is logic

Comment: @jezrael updated description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#changed data samples for better sample data 
print (df)
                 time Status
0 2016-01-15 08:55:00   Open
1 2016-01-15 09:00:00   Plmt
2 2016-01-15 09:05:00   SHRT
3 2016-01-15 09:10:00   Plmt
4 2016-01-15 09:15:00   Open
5 2016-01-15 09:20:00   Plmt
6 2016-01-15 09:25:00   SHRT
7 2016-01-15 09:30:00   SHRT
8 2016-01-15 09:35:00   Plmt
9 2016-01-15 09:40:00   SHRT
```

---

```
#filter only Open and SHRT
df1 = df[df['Status'].isin(['Open','SHRT'])].copy()
#convert column to datetimes
df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])
print (df1)
                 time Status
0 2016-01-15 08:55:00   Open
2 2016-01-15 09:05:00   SHRT
4 2016-01-15 09:15:00   Open
6 2016-01-15 09:25:00   SHRT
7 2016-01-15 09:30:00   SHRT
9 2016-01-15 09:40:00   SHRT

#filter only rows with Open and next row SHRT
m1 = (df1['Status'] == 'Open') & (df1['Status'].shift(-1) == 'SHRT')
m2 = (df1['Status'].shift() == 'Open') & (df1['Status'] == 'SHRT')
df2 = df1[m1 | m2].copy()

#create difference column and set NaT by condition
df2['Diff'] = df2['time'].diff().mask(df2['Status'] == 'Open') 
print (df2)
                 time Status     Diff
0 2016-01-15 08:55:00   Open      NaT
2 2016-01-15 09:05:00   SHRT 00:10:00
4 2016-01-15 09:15:00   Open      NaT
6 2016-01-15 09:25:00   SHRT 00:10:00
```

Comment: After applying `df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])` recieving output:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.`

Comment: @ArtemReznov - Change `df1 = df[df['Status'].isin(['Open','SHRT'])]` to `df1 = df[df['Status'].isin(['Open','SHRT'])].copy()`

Comment: it helped, error gone.
When doing `print(df2)` get output:

`35       NaT
281      NaT
282      NaT
642      NaT`

Comment: @ArtemReznov - What is your pandas version?

Comment: @ArtemReznov - One iedea - if change `df2['Diff'] = np.where(df2['Status'] == 'SHRT', df2['time'].diff(), np.nan) ` to `df2['Diff'] = df2['time'].diff().mask(df2['Status'] == 'Open')` it working correct?

Comment: version is  0.23.4

Comment: YES! `df2['Diff'] = df2['time'].diff().mask(df2['Status'] == 'Open')` changed this, and got output what i want, thanks a lot!!!